# I have a comma delimited string and I want to find one particular field in that using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

This is my string:

```
"0949418001","12/12/2011","12/21/2011","0010043309","EFT  ","Net 10 Days From Ship Date","","","FOB Origin/Collect","","","0000835369","DUPRE TRANSPORTS INC","DUPR      ","0231653047","1/23/2012","Motor Fuel Dest","1049930","8784.00","8796.00","8784.00","UG6  ","N","0.196500","1726.06","25405.51","TAX ","REG","","PASADENA,TX,COP,RFYC (03FV)","   ","0000835369","835369","1726.06","01/23/2012","0.00","23679.45"
```

I want to get the date that is preceding the word `"Motot Fuel Dest"` using regex. How can we get that?

Comment: Regex will get the value but it looks like some form of fixed field text.  For stability, can you not split this into a list and then look at the particular field?  Possibly not but thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 6):

Could use something like this...

```
/(?<=")[^"]+(?=","Motor Fuel Dest)/
```

Depending on your regex flavor the syntax may be different.

**Edit: .NET version of solution**

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, "(?<=\")[^\"]+(?=\",\"Motor Fuel Dest)").Value;
```

It's not something special, just lookbehind/lookahead capture only what you need.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. modified it slightly and it works. Thanks again :-)

Comment: He's using .NET (see the title. I'll add the tag).

Answer (score 0):

This will also work...

```
var dateMatch = Regex.Match(myInputString, @"(?<Date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})"",Motor\sFuel\sDest");

DateTime theValue = DateTime.Parse(dateMatch.Groups["Date"].Value);
```

Then you have the value as a `DateTime` in the `theValue` field.